# Choosing database using radio buttons

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm teaching myself to write an Android app. I use the following code to successfully choose the different database for my app:

```
public void manageDB()
{       
    setContentView(R.layout.dbmanager);     
    ScrollView ll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.lstDb);
    final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    rg.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);     
    for (int i=0; i < mDBList.items.size(); i++)
    {            
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
        rb.setId(VIEW_RADIO_ID + i);
        rb.setText(mDBList.items.get(i).dictionaryName);
        rb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));            
        rg.addView(rb,i);
        if (mDBFile != null && mDBFile.fileName.equals(mDBList.items.get(i).fileName))
        {
            rg.check(VIEW_RADIO_ID + i);
        }            
    }
    ll.addView(rg);

    Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            int selectedIndex = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();  
            if (selectedIndex < 0)
            {
                selectedIndex = 0;
            }               
            mDBFile = mDBList.items.get(selectedIndex - VIEW_RADIO_ID);             
            savePreferences();
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            menuMain();
        }
    });     
  }
```

With this code, I can click on a radio button to choose a database, and the click on the OK button to confirm and return to the main screen. Now I want to assign a button on the main screen to do this task so that I don't have to leave the main screen when choosing a database.

Since I have two pieces of database, ideally I want a two-way button to do this task. I mean when I click on the button, db_1 is chosen. When the button is clicked again db_2 is chosen, and vice versa.

I have no idea how to adapt this code to meet this requirement of mine. I wonder if you guys can give me a little help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's probably a rare case when a single app would have more than 1 database file

Comment: My bad in calling, perhaps but mine is a dictionary app with two pieces of SQlite database: English-my_language and my_language-English.

Comment: two differnt tables . One Database

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to change database in one click instead of two, you could use a radiogroup containing your 2 radiobuttons, [and listen for checked radiobutton change](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener%29).
Then in onCheckedChange() you load the right database.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "Switch" I think it will solve your purpose. Look at the link [here:][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html  Or you can also use the toggle buttons. Hope it helps.